# Store a FIND result as a variable, then test it for errors. Batch

Tags: variables, batch-file, if-statement, find, errorlevel

First off I am a complete novice with batch so I apologize in advanced for my ignorance.  I am trying to find an IPv4 address with the find command, store it, check if it exists and if it doesn't display an error.  I can't seem to figure this one out.

```
ipconfig | find "IPv4" > nul
if %ERRORLEVEL% EQU 0 (
    'then save result as a variable'
) else (
    goto error
)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A way :

```
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
for /f "delims=" %%a in ('ipconfig ^| find "IPv4"') do (
  set $IP=!%%a!
  goto:next)

:next
if defined $IP (echo Your IP is : %$IP:~1%) else (echo error)
```